# MySQL denied me access after changing my password

Tags: mysql, xampp, root

I am new to MySQL. Today is my first day using it through XAMPP. I have managed to change my password using the code

```
mysqladmin -u root password
```

Suddenly I was denied access from XAMPP and from the MySQL Admin portal. I tried to reset the password immediately in the same window using the same command but I was given the error

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I saw a number of related questions here on stackoverflow but they were all about phpMyAdmin password issues.

I would like to rest it to the default password and gain access to MySQL & XAMPP again. I have been going around in circles for an hour. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By default xampp has no password.  Now that you changed the password, you need to configure that in places where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the root is not configured to localhost,
if it is a new database, and can do this safely, you can try:

1. change the my.cnf, set mysql skip-grant-tables
2. restart mysql server, now you can visit the server with any account
3. select data from mysql.user and get the rows that user='root' and get the info.

now: skip-grant-tables is an unsafe parameter in production env, change it back before you put the server online.